# Replace text with another one using found one

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to find all numbers from 4000 to 4999 and replace the leading 4 with 7.

For example:

```
4000 -> 7000
4015 -> 7015
4987 -> 7987
```

I tried replacing `4\d\d\d\d` with `7\1`, but it didn’t work.

Comment: [This has been discussed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188408/give-me-teh-regez-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below for `notepad++`

Search for `4(\d\d\d)` and replace with `7\1`.

Answer (score 3):

Search for `(?<!\d)4(\d{3})(?!\d)` and replace with `7\1`.

**Explanation**

```
(?<!\d)     # Negative lookbehind: check if there is no digit preceding 4
4           # match 4
(           # start group 1
    \d{3}   # match 3 digits
)           # end group 1
(?!\d)      # Negative lookahead: check if there is no digit following the 3 digits
```

Replacement: `\1` refers to group 1.

[image]

**Although** Tim's solution is nicer :p

Comment: @gruber I work with NP++ and tested it out, make sure to check "regular expression" in "search mode"

Comment: Thanks for the last line, but that's not necessarily true. If a number might occur surrounded by letters or underscores, then only yours would find it. Also thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

Search for `\b4(\d{3})\b` and replace with `7\1`, using regular expression replace mode.

The [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) make sure that you don't accidentally match `14000` or `40000`.